# How to use an element from an ID array to show the next element sibling outside the array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a function to display elements [items] from an array. I want to show the next element sibling Outside the array [subitem] when an item is clicked. I want to use Javascript only. I'm really new and with a lot to learn. How can I show the subitem when I click on the item?

I tried some coding but I'm not good with the syntax, so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var ITEMS = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ITEMS.push("IT" + i);
}

function showitems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(ITEMS[i]).style.display = "flex";
  }
}

showitems();

function showsubitem() {
  ITEMS[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "flex";
  });
}

showsubitem();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .item,
    .sub {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="IT0" class="item">
    <p>item 0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 0</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT1" class="item">
    <p>item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT2" class="item">
    <p>item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT3" class="item">
    <p>item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 3</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT4" class="item">
    <p>item 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 4</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT5" class="item">
    <p>item 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 5</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I expect to click an item from the array and show (change to "display:flex;") its respective subitem from outside the array.

Comment: I need the next element sibling outside the array, not the next one in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I used `inline` instead of `flex`. Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) about the `display` property.

Second, while setting the display, I set `click` event listener for each item, that changes the display of the `nextElementSibling`.

```js
var ITEMS = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  ITEMS.push("IT" + i);
}

function showitems() {
  let all_subs = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');
  for (let i = 0; i < ITEMS.length; i++) {
    let currentElement = document.getElementById(ITEMS[i]);
    currentElement.style.display = "inline";
    currentElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
      currentElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = "inline";
    });
  }
}

showitems();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .item,
    .sub {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="IT0" class="item">
    <p>item 0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 0</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT1" class="item">
    <p>item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT2" class="item">
    <p>item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT3" class="item">
    <p>item 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 3</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT4" class="item">
    <p>item 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 4</p>
  </div>

  <div id="IT5" class="item">
    <p>item 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    <p>subitem 5</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```